# How a textfield value can be used as a double in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

We have an outlet in swift 4 like this:

```
@IBOutlet var accured_sum: UITextField!
```

I declared another variable like this:

```
var sum: Double?
```

Now I want to assign Double value of accured_sum to variable sum.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
guard let text = accured_sum.text else { return }
sum = Double(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution, providing a default value

```
sum = Double(TextField.text ?? "0")
```

If sum is not nil, it has the double from the TextField. It is is nil: your textfield was not a double OR you never initialized sum.